# Query SortedList<Object1,Object2> with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sortedlist

I'm a complete begginer with Linq. And I woild like to know, if it is possible to make a query where for a given Class1.Code I get matching Class2.Value.

```
class Class1()
{
    public string Code;
    ...
}

class Class2()
{
    public double Value;
    ...
}

SortedList<Class1, Class2>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.First(x => x.Key.Code == codeToSearch).Value
```

However, this is not efficient (O(n)). I guess this is not the correct way to approach the problem. If you are searching by `Code` most of the time, you should probably make it a `SortedList<string, Class2>` and store `Code` as the key.

Answer (score 1):

```
double value = (from kv in SortedList
                where kv.Key.Code = "CodeI'mLookingFor"
                select kv.Value.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

SortedList < Class1, Class2 > x;

One way to write it:

(from pair in x
 where pair.Key.Code == matchingValue
 select pair.Value.Value)

where matchingValue is the Class1.Code you want to search for.